# Blank graph on offline mathematica

Tags: plotting, manipulate, parametric-functions

I am looking at the following plot:

```
ClearAll[x, y, t, q, d]; 
ode1 = y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t]; 
ode2 = x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]; 
ic = x[0] + y[0] == 1 
sol[t_, d_, q_, x0_, y0_] = 
  {x[t], y[t]} /. 
     (First @ DSolve[{ode1, ode2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]) 
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate @ Table[sol[t, d, q, .25, .75], {d, {0.1}}, {q, {0.9}}], 
    {t, 0, k}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
    FrameLabel -> True, 
    Frame -> True, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}], 
  {k, .1, 400}]
```

But I get a blank plot. What is going on here?

Note: my Mathematica is new, and I get a graph on the online version, but it is very unresponsive.

Comment: Choose initial value for `k` to be small enough, but not 0 exactly, say `{k, 0.01, 400}`. It is impossible to plot from 0 to 0, so MMA complaints. For me `Manipulate` very smooth when I move slider. And use `FrameLabel` if you use `Frame -> True`. About solving ... it is transcendental equation and can't be solved in symbolic closed form.

Comment: Now I am working with `ClearAll[x, y, t, q, d]; ode1 = y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q)
y[t]; ode2 = x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]; ic = x[0] + y[0] == 1 
 
   sol[t_, d_, q_, x0_, y0_] = {x[t], 
    y[t]} /. (First@
     DSolve[{ode1, ode2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t])
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@Table[sol[t, d, q, .25, .75], {d, {0.1}}, {q, {0.9}}], {t, 
   0, k}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, FrameLabel -> True, 
  Frame -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}], {k, .1, 400}]`

Comment: On my online version, it is very laggy, on my personal copy, the graph does not generate

Comment: I just get a blank graph

Comment: I edited the question accordingly

Comment: If you decided to use `Manipulate` you may discover also dependencies on `d` and `q`: `ClearAll[x, y, t, q, d, ode1, ode2, ic, sol]; ode1 = y'[t] == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 q) y[t]; ode2 = x'[t] == 1 - q y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]; ic = x[0] + y[0] == 1; sol[t_, d_, q_, x0_, y0_] = {x[t], y[t]} /. (First@DSolve[{ode1, ode2, x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0}, {x[t], y[t]}, t]); Manipulate[ParametricPlot[sol[t, d, q, .25, .75], {t, 0, k},PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}], {{k, 0.01,"time"}, 0.01, 400}, {d,0.1, 1}, {q, 0.1, 1}]`.

Comment: You may also include `x0` and `y0` to variables of `Manipulate`.

Comment: If you change `DSolve[...]` to `Simplify[DSolve[...]]` that will take longer to calculate, but will reduce the complexity of the solution by about 4x and thus try to make your `Manipulate` more responsive. Next, would it be possible to edit your question to indicate whether you now no longer get no graph, now no longer "laggy", etc? Can you quantify this? How many minutes does it take for the `Plot` to update? That way people can tell what progress you have made and what you are seeing?

Comment: For the offline version, the graph doesn't ever show any functions even if I play with all the sliders, autorun it, or reload it. For the online version, It is now much more responsive

Comment: For your offline version replace `Plot` with `Table`, eliminating the `Manipulate` for a moment and just substitute some assigned values to the variables. What does the `Table` show? Does it include any variable instead of just constants? Does it include some `I` somewhere indicating complex? Tweak the step size in the `Table` if need be. Can you discover any odd value in that with might keep `Plot` from working? (This is a classic trick/method of diagnosing why a `Plot` is blank.) If you can't find any reason that `Plot` isn't working then check if `Plot[qqq^2,{qqq,-1,1}]` displays.

Comment: There was a problem with sol! Thanks for the approach. You are very helpful

Comment: Which problem? I suggested you only what I tried myself and what definitely works.

Comment: Yes, I believe I input something incorrectly into sol. You were also very helpful. Thank you for your advice, and I apologize for missing some of your code.